# Как работает метод HasFlag в C#, и можно ли его заменить методом equals() в java?

Tags: java, c#

```
public enum AccountInfoUpdateType
{
    None = 0,
    AccountInfo = 1,
    RiskInfo = 2,
    TradingStatistic = 4,
    All = TradingStatistic | RiskInfo | AccountInfo,
}


public class CryptoAccountInfoUpdate : ClientData
{
    public AccountInfoUpdateType AccountInfoUpdateType { get; set; }


    public CryptoAccountInfoUpdate(AccountInfoUpdateType accountInfoUpdateType) 
    {
      if (accountInfoUpdateType.HasFlag((Enum) AccountInfoUpdateType.TradingStatistic))
      {
    //some code
      }
    }
```

Я только учусь, поэтому вопрос может и глупый. Не судите строго.

Comment: Нет нельзя. Он выполняет сравнение `this & flag == flag`. Это не то же самое, что Equals

Comment: Другими словами, понятие: `включает` и `совпадает (ровно)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В яве нет конструкции аналогичной `enum` из C#.

Для получения той же функциональности придется использовать `int` константы и немного битовой магии.

Например есть

```
 int None = 0;
 int AccountInfo = 1;
 int RiskInfo = 2;
 int TradingStatistic = 4;
```

узнать выставлен ли флаг в `foo` можно так

```
if(foo & AccountInfo != 0) {
    // флаг выставлен
} else {
    // флаг не выставлен
}
```

выставить флаг можно так

```
foo |= AccountInfo;
```

сбросить

```
foo &= ~AccountInfo;
```

Comment: вроде как `enum` вполне [присутствует](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Да, но он устроен по другому. В .Net это синтаксичиский сахар для `int` поэтому срабатывают штуки вроде `EnumValue` | EnumValue2`, а в Java это просто класс специального вида со спрятанным конструктором и несколькими инстансами.

Comment: но там же можно добавить в этот класс метод `hasFlag`?

Comment: @Grundy да, а вот сделать `EnumValue | EnumValue2` нельзя, потому что нет подходящего инстанса.

Comment: а операторы не перегружаются?

Comment: В джаве нет, но это и не помогло бы. Проблема в том что нет инстанса представляющего собой объединение двух флагов (если конечно не завести значения для всех возможных комбинаций).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88661/discussion-between-grundy-and-talex).

Comment: Извините, а foo ето инстанс енама AccountInfoUpdateType?

Comment: Это int. В яве придется работать с примитивными типами.

Comment: окей понятно но где мы провозглошаем переменную foo? в самом енаме?

Comment: спасибо, уже разобрался. использовал enumset и проверяю через contains()

Comment: `EnumSet` это как раз то что нужно. Почему я про него забыл.